# Update query with subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

Does this abstracted SQL query solution? I need to update rows using a subquery with `where`.

[image: Screenshot of query]

```
UPDATE articles
SET varcount = (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        articles
    WHERE
        parentid = articles.id
)
WHERE
    articles.parentid = '';
```

Comment: you need to make an alias inside your subquery i think..

Comment: This is just an `UPDATE` query. We know nothing about the actual problem you are trying to solve. Also, please edit your post to include any queries or sample data as well formatted text.

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Hope would not mistake what you want to do, just try following query:

```
update articles
join (
    select parentid, count(*) cnt
    from articles
    group by parentid
) t on articles.id = t.parentid
set articles.varcount = t.cnt
where articles.parentid = ''
```